# Builder::XmlMarkup Is vulnerable to XXE attack in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, rubygems

We are using Builder::XmlMarkup for creating the XML with Ruby On Rails. Can someone tell me Builder::XmlMarkup is vulnerable to 'External Entity Reference ('XXE')' attack?

Thanks,
Tushar